# Problemas com decimais na string SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estou com um erro: toda vez que a variável c.Valor_do_titulo passa pela string SQL, automaticamente, o "." que separa o Decimal é convertido para ",".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver nessa imagem, a variável está utilizando do "." normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, a string SQL tira o ponto e coloca vírgula.

O que pode ser?

A varável está com 80.90, mas quando é colocada dentro da string sql se torna 80,90.

Como o número está indo com vírgula, o SQl interpreta como parte da sintaxe dando erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
public static void salvar(Mov_lancamento c, Int64 user)
{
    String sql;

    sql = "SELECT id_lancamento FROM mov_lancamento WHERE favorecido = '"+c.Favorecido+"' AND valor_do_titulo = "+ c.Valor_do_titulo + " AND data_vencimento = '"+c.Data_vencimento+"'";

    SqlDataReader dtr = Suporte.ConexaoBanco.selecionar(sql);

    if(dtr.Read())
        Id_lancamento = (Int64)dtr["id_lancamento"];
    else Id_lancamento = 0;

    dtr.Close();

    // Se tem 'id' igual a zero é porque ainda não foi inserido
    if (Id_lancamento == 0)
    {
        sql = "INSERT INTO mov_lancamento VALUES ('" + c.Favorecido + "', '" + c.Data_lancamento + "', '" + c.Data_vencimento + "', '" + c.Documento + "', " + Convert.ToDecimal(c.Valor_do_titulo.ToString().Replace(".", ",")) + ", " + c.Valor_pago + ", " + c.Acrecimo_valor + "," + c.Descontos_valor + "," + c.Saldo_a_pagar + ", " + c.Pago + ", '" + c.Data_pagamento + "', " + c.Excluido + ")";
        Suporte.ConexaoBanco.executar(sql);
    }
    else // Senão apenas atualiza
    {
        sql = "UPDATE mov_lancamento SET favorecido = '" + c.Favorecido + "', data_lancamento ='" + c.Data_lancamento + "', data_vencimento = '" + c.Data_vencimento + "', tipo_documento = " + c.Documento + ", " + Convert.ToDecimal(c.Valor_do_titulo.ToString().Replace(".", ","))  + ", pago = " + c.Pago + ", data_pagamento = '" + c.Data_pagamento + "' , excluido = 0 WHERE id_lancamento =" + c.Id_lancamento;
        Suporte.ConexaoBanco.executar(sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o código e descrição do erro, não o print da sua tela. Qual é a mensagem de erro retornada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que o sistema possui uma configuração de globalização, por padrão está sendo utilizado a cultura do seu servidor que provavelmente é pt-BR (Português-Brasil). O que você pode fazer é alterar essa configuração para o padrão americano, assim irá ficar no formato desejado.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Caso não queira modificar essas configurações você pode realizar um replace na sua variável que contém o valor.

```
//Esse N2 configura a quantidade de casas decimais serão formatadas na sua variável.
//N2: duas casas decimais
//N3: três casas decimais
//N4: quatro casas decimais
//...
c.Valor_do_titulo.ToString("N2").Replace(",", ".");
```

Answer (score 2):

Caso não queira que o ponto seja convertido para vírgula, você pode fazer uso do *NumberFormatInfo*, setando a propriedade *NumberDecimalSeparator*.

```cs
        var valor = 100.5M; //decimal
        var formatter = new NumberFormatInfo
        {
            NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
        };

        var comVirgula = valor.ToString(formatter); // resultado : 100,5        
        formatter.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        var comPonto = valor.ToString(formatter); // resultado : 100.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar questões de conversão, principalmente em variáveis numéricas ou de datas, a definição de parâmetros a partir do `SqlCommand` é recomendada.

[Exemplo retirado no Developer Network da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;

    // Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics.
    // SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```